# Error in postgresql 8.3 restore database

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, restore

when i try to restore my database ,it shows error

> could not create large object 515025

in pgAdmin and command line as well

its not working even if i am creating another backup

any suggestion?

Comment: What command and more specifically sql statement is generating this error?  Your postgresql log file should help here.  I wasn't under the impression that pg_dump archived large objects (there is a contributed pg_dumplo which does that).

Comment: i got solution, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got solution
before restoring database i used to delete all tables, but when i delete whole database and create new one, then restore is done successfully